# Java CompilationTask/ClassLoader from user define source failed to "call"

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction, task, loader

I'm trying the sample code from [Core java programming] volume 2, chapter 8, with tiny modification. First. I've build a intellij project, with a simple class and "f()" function, already compiled:

```
public class BasicTypes {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("BasicTypes.f()");
    }
}
```

Then I have 2 classes to load class:

```
class StringBuilderJavaSource extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private StringBuilder code;

    public StringBuilderJavaSource(String className) {
        super(URI.create("string:///" + className.replace('.', '/') + Kind.SOURCE.extension),
                Kind.SOURCE);
        code = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
        System.out.println(code);
        return code;
    }

    public void append(String s) {
        code.append(s);
        code.append('\n');
    }
}

class ByteArrayJavaClass extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream stream;

    public ByteArrayJavaClass(String className) {
        super(URI.create("bytes:///" + className), Kind.CLASS);
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
        return stream;
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

And then the main function:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    final List<ByteArrayJavaClass> classFileObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnosticCollector = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
    JavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnosticCollector, null, null);
    fileManager = new ForwardingJavaFileManager<JavaFileManager>(fileManager) {
        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(
                Location location,
                final String className,
                JavaFileObject.Kind kind,
                FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Enter getJavaFileForOutput");
            if (className.startsWith("x.")) {
                ByteArrayJavaClass fileObject = new ByteArrayJavaClass(className);
                classFileObjects.add(fileObject);
                System.out.println("Enter x");
                return fileObject;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Enter others");
                return super.getJavaFileForOutput(location, className, kind, sibling);
            }
        }
    };

    StringBuilderJavaSource source = new StringBuilderJavaSource("myFirstClass");
    source.append("package x;");
    source.append("public class myFirstClass extends " + "BasicTypes" + " {");
    source.append("    public void f(){System.out.println(\"myFirstClass.f()\");}");
    source.append("}");
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnosticCollector,
            null, null, Arrays.asList(source));
    Boolean result = task.call();
    if (!result) {
        System.out.println("Compilation failed");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The program fails to compile and prints:

```
package x;
public class myFirstClass extends BasicTypes {
    public void f(){System.out.println("myFirstClass.f()");}
}

Compilation failed
```

Seems the failure doesn't have enough information for me to do tourble-shooting.
So where did I get wrong in my program, and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.